# Asymptotic behaviour- double sum of Stirling numbers of the second kind- Hayman's Method

Tags: combinatorics, asymptotics, approximation, stirling-numbers

My goal is to find a lower bound for \begin{equation}\sum_{0\leq l\leq k\leq n}S(n,k)S(k,l)\end{equation}, where $S(n,k)$ denotes the Stirling numbers of the second kind. I first tried to use the maximum for the stirling number $S(n,k)$ which happens at $k=n/\log(n)$ but this decreases $k$ to much, and the second factor in the product gets pretty small, thus I tried $\sum_{0\leq l\leq k\leq n}S(n,k)S(k,l) \geq S(n,n/2)S(n/2,n/4)$. It turned out that an estimate for $\log(S(n,n/2))$ is given by \begin{equation}(n/2 +1)\log(n/2) - n/2\log(2) + 3/n  \end{equation}

Therefore I get the following inequality:
\begin{equation}
\sum_{0\leq l\leq k\leq n}S(n,k)S(k,l)\geq e^{3n/4\log(n)- 3n/4\log(2) + 15/n}
\end{equation}
However I also now that 
$\sum_{k=0}^nS(n,k)=B_n$ ($B_n$= Bell number) grows as $e^{n\log(n)- n\log(\log(n))-n}$ and thus the leading order is $e^{n\log(n)}$ 
Shouldn't my sum grow faster? Was my attempt wrong, or what could be a better one?

Thanks a lot for any Inputs!

Answer (score 1):

If we break this up as a double sum, we get
$$\sum_{k=0}^n S(n,k) \sum_{\ell=0}^k S(k,\ell) = \sum_{k=0}^n S(n,k) B_k$$
The values of this sum as $n$ varies are sequence [A000258](http://oeis.org/A000258) in the OEIS.

In the OEIS, we see the exponential generating function $\exp(\exp(\exp(x)-1)-1)$ which I'm sure follows from the exponential formula. This lets us hope to get asymptotics for the sequence by looking at the e.g.f., for example by Hayman's method: see Theorem 5.4.1 in [Wilf's generatingfunctionology](https://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/gfology2.pdf).

(I tried working on this for a bit. It's straightforward but painful, so I suggest looking through the references in the OEIS to see if anyone else has done it, first.)

Comment: Yes, I do know that it is the above sum. I do not now the Hayman method so I will look up your reference. Thanks

Comment: Asymptotically, yes. If you write $r_n = e^{e^{x_n}}$, my initial calculations suggested $x_n \sim \frac{e n}{\log n \log \log n}$.

Comment: confused, sorry. How do you get this?

Comment: We have $a(r) = r \frac{f'(r)}{f(r)} = r e^{e^r + r -1}$, which becomes $\frac{x}{e} \log x \log \log x$ when we make the substitution $r = e^{e^x}$. So we start by setting $x = en$ (which gets us $a(r) = n \log n \log \log n$ instead of $n$), and then correct for this by diving by logs.

Comment: If $f(x) = e^{g(x)}$, then $f'(x) = e^{g(x)} g'(x)$ and therefore $\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} = g'(x)$. This tells us that $\frac{a(r)}{r}$ is the derivative of $e^{e^r-1}-1$, which is $e^{e^r-1} \cdot e^r = e^{e^r + r - 1}$.

Comment: It's plausible. I don't have much intuition for the Stirling numbers. Have you done any numerical experiments?